# Chrome developer tools cannot find HttpRequest

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, python-requests

In Python, I'm using the `requests` library to POST an HTTPRequest to a URL. When I click this button however, it looks like nothing happens when following Chrome Developer Tools. No XHR requests, nothing is POSTed.

When I click the button, a new window is opened, then immediately redirected to another page. I'd like `requests` to POST a payload, then store the returned page after the redirect.

Here's the button in the HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="form_submit" class="querysubmit" name="querysubmit" onclick="if (document.regform.onsubmit()) {$j('#queryform').submit();setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'form_submit\').disabled=false;document.getElementById(\'form_submit_image\').src=\'/img/btn_submitquery.gif\';',10000);this.disabled=true;document.getElementById('form_submit_image').src='/img/btn_querysubmitted.gif';}">
                     <img id="form_submit_image" src="/img/btn_submitquery.gif" alt="Submit Query">
                </button>
```

I'm trying to find the POST HTTPRequest so that I can add a payload to the request.

```
new_page = session.post(QUERY_URL, data=payload_dict)
```

Does anyone know why when I hit the "Submit" button, nothing occurs in Chrome Developer tools yet a new page opens that processes the request?

Comment: Why is the JS inlined?

Comment: does the page open in a new tab? if so, then the network activity will be there. you can remember activity across reload via an option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the "Preserve Log" option in the Network Panel. This will save the primary request information (but not the raw data!) for requests on page movement.

Your issue stems from the "immediately redirected to another page". When page movement  occurs, DevTools dumps everything it can to conserve memory. You would be better off using AJAX to submit the request and handle any response, that way no page redirect occurs.

Comment: I've toggled on "Preserve Log" but there still seems to be no new network activity after hitting the Submit button. It's almost like I need to see the network activity on the newly opened page, but by the time I open up Developer Tools, the page is already redirected (about .5 seconds). Is there a Python package you'd recommend for using AJAX to submit the request? I assume the 'requests' package is not capable?

Comment: Python can't submit ajax requests. It is a server-side language (or host machine.) Only JavaScript is currently capable of this. You need to use an XMLHttpRequest or fetch object to handle the request. Catch the submit event of the form, then create the AJAX request and send it. Finally, handle the response from the server (whether it be redirect or what have you.) If you are meaning to open a new tab/window, that is why. You can't capture pages on load, it will need a reload so this is breaking your debug cycle. I'd say, question whether you *really* need to open a new window on form submit.